# How to get only string from mysql result?

Tags: python

I need to get the string out of mysql result query

```
mycursor.execute("Select text from text_table")
myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
rows=[i[0] for i in myresult]
for x in myresult:
    print(x[0])
```

It only returns one row but it returns in this format:

```
(u'I need this string',)
```

I tried this

```
rows=[i[0] for i in myresult]
print(myresult)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your syntax is off.  Try this version:

```
mycursor.execute("Select text from text_table")
myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
for row in myresult:
    print(row[0])
```

The offending line of code might be this:

```
rows=[i[0] for i in myresult]
```

This appears to be consuming the cursor by iterating through the entire result set.